# How to make a drag and drop in Grid Layout in Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

What I want to achieve is to drag red box view and drop in on the aqua boxview. The aqua box view should then take the place of the redbox view. How can I achieve this in Xamarin Forms ? I have added the following XAML code below. Please someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Xamarin.Forms does not support drag-n-drop out of the box, hence you'll have to implement it yourself. It won't be easy, since there are certainly some edge cases to consider, but it's achievable. Basically the steps could be (maybe there are other options)

- Add an `AbsoluteLayout` that wraps your `Grid`
- Add an `PanGestureRecognizer`
- When the pan gesture starts, check if it's on the red `BoxView`
- If so, move the red `BoxView` to the `AbsoluteLayout` and remove it from the `Grid`
- Move the red `BoxView` if the pan is updated
- When the users stops the pan, check whether the red `BoxView` where you'd expect it to be dropped
- If so, drop it (whatever that means in the context of your app)
- If not, animate it back to its original position, remove it from the `AbsoluteLayout` and add it to the `Grid`

If you have tried to implement it and are stuck with a more concrete issue, feel free to ask another question about it.

Comment: @jones Since I don't know your exact requirements, no. What exactly do you want to do with the `BoxView`?

Comment: I should be able to drag the box view and drop it on another box view having the same grid values (meaning, the box view's size is same). Then where I am dropping the boxview, the other boxview takes the place of the dragged boxview.

Comment: @jones Well, then you'll have to get the `Grid.Column` and `Grid.Row` of the target `BoxView`, set the respective values on the dragged `BoxView` and add the latter to the `Grid` with `Grid.Children.Add`

Comment: Pheew. This seems complex. Do you have an example code ? or a code snippet where I can get started ? Please.

Comment: @jones Yeah, it *is*  complex, like I stated in my answer. Unfortunately I have not implemented it myself, hence I can't provide code. Maybe I can make a simple sample implementation, but I don't know when I'll be able to.

Comment: Please let me have that sample implementation. Will be greatly useful to me & other developers around. Thanks bro.

Comment: **One more thing**: It seems as if there is no possibility to get the X/Y coordinates of the `PanGestureRecognizer`, hence you'll have to implement platform specific gestures, in order to get the X/Y coordinates.

Comment: Hmm I see.. Please provide a sample if you can bro :(